# How to check if there is only consecutive ones and zeros in bytestream

Tags: python, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I want to check if an int/long consists only of one set of consecutive ones or zero. For example `111100000`, `1100000` but not `101000`.

I have a basic implementation as follows:

```
def is_consecutive(val):
        count = 0        
        while val %2 == 0:
            count += 1
            val = val >> 1
        return (0xFFFFFFFF >> count ) & val
```

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: It's not clear what counts as "consecutive ones or zero". Does 110011 count? What about 10? 0? And is this in binary or decimal? Can you give a more complete description of the property you're trying to test for?

Comment: No only one set of consecutive ones and zeros.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a number `n`, `n | (n - 1)` will be all ones *if and only if* it meets the pattern you describe.

A number `x` that is all ones is one less than a power of two. You can [check for a power of two by ANDing it with itself minus one](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2). Or in other words, `x` is all one bits if `x & (x + 1) == 0`.

```
def is_consecutive(n):
    x = n | (n - 1)
    return x & (x + 1) == 0
```

This test program checks numbers against both a regex and `is_consecutive`, printing asterisks when each of the two tests passes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

def is_consecutive(n):
    x = n | (n - 1)
    return x & (x + 1) == 0

for n in range(64):
    print('*' if re.fullmatch('0b1*0*', bin(n)) else ' ',
          '*' if is_consecutive(n) else ' ',
          n, bin(n))
```

Empirical testing confirms this works up to at least 64. As you can see, the asterisks match up perfectly.

```
* * 0 0b0
* * 1 0b1
* * 2 0b10
* * 3 0b11
* * 4 0b100
    5 0b101
* * 6 0b110
* * 7 0b111
* * 8 0b1000
    9 0b1001
    10 0b1010
    11 0b1011
* * 12 0b1100
    13 0b1101
* * 14 0b1110
* * 15 0b1111
* * 16 0b10000
    17 0b10001
    18 0b10010
    19 0b10011
    20 0b10100
    21 0b10101
    22 0b10110
    23 0b10111
* * 24 0b11000
    25 0b11001
    26 0b11010
    27 0b11011
* * 28 0b11100
    29 0b11101
* * 30 0b11110
* * 31 0b11111
* * 32 0b100000
    33 0b100001
    34 0b100010
    35 0b100011
    36 0b100100
    37 0b100101
    38 0b100110
    39 0b100111
    40 0b101000
    41 0b101001
    42 0b101010
    43 0b101011
    44 0b101100
    45 0b101101
    46 0b101110
    47 0b101111
* * 48 0b110000
    49 0b110001
    50 0b110010
    51 0b110011
    52 0b110100
    53 0b110101
    54 0b110110
    55 0b110111
* * 56 0b111000
    57 0b111001
    58 0b111010
    59 0b111011
* * 60 0b111100
    61 0b111101
* * 62 0b111110
* * 63 0b111111
```

Answer (score 0):

If speed is an issue, you could just generate a dictionary of all acceptable values, or hardcode them. After all, I think there are only 64 possible values for a 32bit int, and 128 possible values for a 64bit long

e.g. here are all 8 possible values for 4 bits:

```
0000
0001
0011
0111
1111
1110
1100
1000
```

Comment: You missed `0010`, `0100`, and `0110`. Leading `0`s don't count.

Comment: Why would leading zeros not count? The OP specified *"only one set of consecutive ones and zeros"*.

Comment: Because all numbers have an infinite number of implicit leading `0`s. The OP's function accepts `int`s not `str`s.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def is_consecutive(seq):
    if len([k for k,g in groupby(seq)]) > 2:
        return False
    return True

def is_consecutive_num(num):
    return is_consecutive(str(bin(num))[2:])

print is_consecutive('111100000')
print is_consecutive('1100000')
print is_consecutive('101000')
print is_consecutive('01')
print is_consecutive('00111100000')
print is_consecutive('000000000')
print is_consecutive_num(400) # 110010000
print is_consecutive_num(96)  # 1100000
print is_consecutive_num(40)  # 101000
```

### Output:

```
True
True
False
True
False
True
False
True
False
```